# APK Expansion Files and APK size

Tags: java, android, apk

I'm developìng an image-based application with the following properties:

- The apk size, without the images is about 15MB for the phone version and 25MB for the tablet version.
- The total size for the images are about 30MB.
- The aplication will be released in a beta status frequent updates will be probable
- The images pack is not likely to be updated

My question is: Can I use the  apk expansion file system? Or Google will give me problems when I try to upload an apk of 15MB and a expansion of 30MB (total 45MB)? Else how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

45mb is within the 50mb allowed for apks. It is generally recommended for apps that surpass the 50mb limit as on most devices the expansion files will be downloaded as the same time as the user downloads your apk [(reference)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html), nevertheless you're completely fine using it in the way you suggested.